# Coloring the edges of a complete graph with two colors.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

$K_4$ is the complete graph with 4 vertices. Let's color the edges in the graph with two colors. How would one go about proving the following statement:

> There is always a monochromatic path of length 3 on the graph.

It seems obvious, but I have no idea how to prove this. $K_4$ has 6 edges, so the best you can do to avoid coloring with the same color too much is to has 3 edges per color. It seems like it's not possible to choose any set of three edges in $K_4$ that don't form a single path. But how would one prove this?

---

Also, is there a meaningful result when you generalize this question:

Let $P_n$ be the length of the longest monochromatic path that must exist when you color the edges of $K_n$ with two colors.

It's trivial to show that $P_1 = 0$, $P_2 = 1$, and $P_3 = 2$. As stated above, I am pretty sure that $P_4 = 3$. Can we say anything about $P_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the $\binom{4}{3}=4$ triangles is monochromatic we are done. Otherwise, by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there are at least two distinct triangles with two sides of one color, say color 1, and one side of the other one, say color 2. Then  there is a monochromatic path of length 3 of color 1 along the sides of those two triangles (note that any couple of triangles in $K_4$ share two vertices).

For the general case see [Theorem of Gerencser-Gyarfas](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.05119.pdf) ("On Ramsey-type problems", Ann. Sci. Budapest. Eotvos Sect. Math, 10 (1967), 167-170): Let $n$ be a positive integer. In every 2-coloring of the edges of $K_n$, there exists a monochromatic path on at least $\lceil(2n+ 1)/3\rceil$ vertices. Furthermore, there exists a 2-coloring of the edges of $K_n$ such that the longest monochromatic path has $\lceil(2n+ 1)/3\rceil$ vertices.

Comment: How would you generalize this to all $n$?

Comment: @XYZT Please see my edit

Comment: Wow, that's incredible that this exact problem has been solved (the formulation is identical too!). Thanks!

Comment: How is the second statement of the theorem you mention different from the first statement?

Comment: The two statements are not in contradiction. Together they say that $\lceil(2n+ 1)/3\rceil$ is the exact lower bound.